# iteration k of simple equation

Tags: matlab

How to create right function to m file of this problem matlab?

one way run.

i have to change always k at 1, 2,3 ,4,5,6...

how to run it in one times debug?

w=8; constant  (edit this value should be erased)

.

k=1,2,3,4,5,6,7..etc; i have to change it as 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7...

.

x=2; constant

a=0.2 ; constant

w=(0:0.3:3)

.

S=[1-exp(-a.*x.*k.*w)];

.

figure(2)

plot(w,S,'-+');

xlabel('w');

ylabel('S');

hold off

(should be hold on) edit

Comment: i  have equation S=[1-exp(-a.*x.*k.*w)]; k is not constant.

Comment: Can you please format your code to make it look like MATLAB? From what I'm seeing right now, you are simply calculating a vector S based on a single k. are you asking how to write a for loop to have it do all the "k"s?

Comment: yes actually i asked so, but my question title will not pass the filter title.

Comment: recently i always do it manually, one by one input k. my big problem is not this actually but i have to also calculate the deferiansial of (S3-S2)/(S2-S1), (S4-S3)/(S3-S2), (S5-S4)/(S4-S3), (S6-S5)/(52-S4), etc

Comment: also why is w=8 and then 0:0.3:3?

Comment: yes it is my bad, w should be not there as 8.sorry. and the figure should be hold on

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am assuming is the answer to your question, but it's still not clear at all:

```
for k=1:N %where N is the highest number you want k to be

x = 2;
a = 0.2;
w = 0:0.3:3;

S = 1 - exp(-a * x * k * w);

figure(2)
plot(w,S,'-+');
xlabel('w');
ylabel('S');
hold off

end
```

obviously you will change the hold/plotting parameters as you wish depending on what you want the graphs to do - leave the hold on and keep plotting on the same figure to show S for various `k`s or plot a new figure for each k.

edit: regarding your updated goal, use the [diff](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) function to generate the S3-S2, S2-S1 etc components in say `Sdiff`, then create a new shifted vector `SdiffPrime` that you pad with a value on one side, and do a `Sdiff./SdiffPrime`. This will provide all the difference ratios you want. Then plot that accordingly as well

Comment: many many many thx. it is very simple for you but for me it is big case, i am so blindly in Matlab. wow, only that? many many thx again. it is worked. i am very glad.

Comment: actually my target is i want to calculate from that plots the :

(S3-S2)/(S2-S1),

(S4-S3)/(S3-S2),

(S5-S4)/(S4-S3),

(S6-S5)/(52-S4),

and soon, Sn...

where in this case S is my y value or ylabel.

this Sn lies at same straight axis x.

Comment: many thx AK4749 my best greeting for you. i follow your instruction now.